# The minimal value of k for making a inequality true

Tags: gm.general-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

I was wondering...
What is the minimal value of $k$ for making the following inequality true.

$(\sum_{x=1}^k (n-x)*x) > nˆ2$.

Is there a way to know that? And how can I prove it?

I was expecting answers like "For every $k > \frac{n}{2}$ the inequality above is true". And my target is the minimal value of $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica helps you in such a way:

```
ForAll[n, n \[Element] Integers && n >= 1,Sum[(n - x)*x, {x, 1, k}] > n^2]
```

> $$\forall _{n,n\in \mathbb{Z}\land n\geq 1}-\frac{1}{6} k (k+1) (2 k-3 n+1)>n^2  $$

```
Reduce[-(1/6) k (1 + k) (1 + 2 k - 3 n) > n^2 && n >= 1 &&  k >= 0, k, Integers]
```

> $$(n|k)\in \mathbb{Z}\land n\geq 7\land \text{Root}\left[2 \text{$\#$1}^3+\text{$\#$1}^2 (3-3 n)+\text{$\#$1} (1-3 n)+6 n^2\&,2\right]<k<\text{Root}\left[2 \text{$\#$1}^3+\text{$\#$1}^2 (3-3 n)+\text{$\#$1} (1-3 n)+6 n^2\&,3\right] $$

```
Series[Root[6 n^2 + (1 - 3 n) #1 + (3 - 3 n) #1^2 + 2 #1^3 &, 2], {n,  Infinity, 2}]
```

> $$\sqrt{2} \sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{89 \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}{72 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{32}{27 n}+\frac{19973 \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3/2}}{6912 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{914}{243 n^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{5/2}\right) $$

Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.